# How in to stringstream put a string

Tags: c++, string, stl, stringstream

I have a vector:

```
vector<stringstream*> ssv;
for (int i = 0; i < cIter; i++) {
    ssv.push_back(new std::stringstream);
}
```

How can I put in elements of vector ssv strings?

I try:

```
string s1 = "easfef" + '\n';
int i = 0;
*ssv[i] << s1 << '\n';
```

But it give me an empty string:

```
string sdf = ssv[i]->str();
```

How can I do it?

Thanks for helping with '\n', but it is stil a problem with vector:
if i write:

```
std::string s1 = "qwerqwr\n";   // for example
int i = 0;
*ssv[i] << s1;
```

But give me an empty string as before

```
string sdf = ssv[i]->str();
```

Comment: `"easfef" + '\n'` is not good.

Comment: why do you want to store stringstream in vector?

Comment: Why use pointers for the `stringstream`?

Comment: I want to take from stringsream strings in next steps for sorting. Each element of vector will be contain several strings(text format)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Well, they aren't copyable, so unless moving is an option, you can't. That's at the low level, though. It could be solved through a higher level problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is how you initialize the string:

```
"easfef" + '\n'
```

The `"easfef"` decays into a `const char *` and `'\n'` is promoted to an `int` with the value 10 (assuming ASCII). Then, the two are added together, which results in a pointer that points somewhere beyond your string literal. A crash is very possible, along with your mother being eaten by a dinosaur.

An easy way to fix this is to enforce `std::string`:

```
std::string s1 = std::string("easfef") + '\n';
```

An easier way is to inline the newline:

```
std::string s1 = "easfef\n";
```

Comment: +1 - `A crash is very possible, along with your mother being eaten by a dinosaur.` - Just, lol :D

Comment: @webnoob, I have no regrets.

Comment: Good, you have done all you can to save his mother from that dreadful dinosaur ..

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
string s1 = "easfef" + '\n';
```

the initialization expression will in practice compute as

```
"easfef" + 10;
```

which is a pointer to the eleventh character of the string.

But there is no such, so you have **Undefined behavior**.

---

Fix:

```
string s1 = string() + "easfef" + '\n';
```

---

That said, a vector of pointers to `stringstream` is almost certainbly an impractical solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Try to describe the higher level problem.

Comment: Why would you choose to construct an empty temporary string and add that to "easfef", producing another temporary string, rather than construct a temporary string with easfef as constructor argument? And why not suggest putting the '\n' constant into the string literal?

Comment: @Agentlien, It probably didn't cross his mind. I didn't realize that it was a string plus a character until I was typing out my first suggestion.

Comment: Well, I try to solve items 4-5 from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting  where my elements - strings from .txt file

Comment: @chris Probably, that simple answer didn't cross *my* mind. <.<

Comment: @Agentlien: re the `string() + `, because maintainability is better the way I wrote it. your suggestion would be a **premature optimization** of an irrelevant detail. it would be severely ungood to incur a cost of programmer time to prematurely optimize an expression that first of all doesn't count towards execution time overall, and secondly which the compiler most likely does automatically for you anyway. whenever the urge to premature optimization gets hold of you, remember, *don't do it*. And next time (a few minutes later), *don't do it yet*. Then if still urge, **MEASURE** first!

Comment: @Agentlien: re not suggesting `"asdljk\n"`, that would go towards *guessing* the intent, some reason for the original expression. If I had to guess I would instead guess that the `\n` was most likely there in order to support a later output statement, and I would suggest removing it entirely and do that in the statement instead. which would increase maintainability (e.g. using that string in contexts where a newline was not desired). but for this answer I chose to not guess at the OP's further programming problems. there is an infinity of possible such problems.

Comment: I agree about premature optimization, but supplying that string as an argument makes the code clearer and no less maintainable. It's also shorter than the empty argument plus literal, so it's easier to type originally and not an "optimization " per say. I do agree to that argument of clarity and maintainability *may* hold for the added character, assuming you may want to replace it with another string in the future.

Comment: @Agentlien: no, **it's not subjective** what's most maintainable. in an expression `string("blah")+"foo"` removing the "blah" involves more editing and thinking than in an expression `string() + "blah" + "foo"`. for (the premature) optimization use a string builder instead of trying to help the compiler optimize the concatenation (which is pretty silly thing to do).

Comment: I never made a case for run-time efficiency, only clarity of semantics and intention. Easy readability trumps shaving half seconds off time editing any time, and I really don't see how such a change would take longer (mentally or mechanically). I do, however think that the "empty string plus string literal plus character literal" is nonobvious compared to "std::string from literal plus character literal".

Comment: well adding `string() +` was shortest for me to write. the rest of the expression is the same as the OP intuitively (but incorrectly wrt. weird C++ rules) chose. so i can't say i am convinced even one little iota by your arguments, neither regarding maintainability nor regarding readability.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ string literals are raw arrays of **chars**, and arrays can be treated as pointers, and character literals like '\n' can be treated as numbers, so `"easfef" + '\n'` is interpreted as a pointer arithmetic operation.

You should write:

```
string s1 = "easfef";
s1 += '\n';
```